# remove multiple long lines from large file (TCL or shell)

Tags: grep, tcl

I have a 2.5G long ascii file with about 3.7M lines. Some lines are long. Lines will have funny characters that cmds might interpret as escape or special characters. (slashes, backslashes, all sort of braces etc.)

I have a series of specific grep cmds that will extract 16 lines from the file. I want to remove those 16 lines from the big file.

```
grep pat1 bigfile | grep -v pat2 | grep -v pat3 | grep -v pat4 > temp
```

The lines in temp are ~10MB long.

Now I want to invert that selection such that the files that are in temp are removed from bigfile.

I tried

```
grep -v -f temp bigfile > newbigfile
```

Result was "grep: Memory exhausted".

I have unix shell and simple TCL scripts at my disposal to do this.

Thanks
Gert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While holding a few tens of MB in memory is trivial for a Tcl program, you don't want to hold all 2.5GB in memory at once if you can help it. That means that we want to keep the lines to exclude in memory and stream the data through:

```
# Load the exclusions into a list
set f [open "temp"]
set linesToExclude [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Stream the main data through...
set fIn [open "bigfile"]
set fOut [open "newbigfile" "w"]
while {[gets $fIn line] >= 0} {
    # Only print the line if it isn't in our exclusions
    if {$line ni $linesToExclude} {  # 'ni' for Not In
        puts $fOut $line
    }
}
close $fOut
close $fIn
```

In general, I'd not want to work with lines of text more than a few hundred bytes long. Beyond that, it starts to feel like working with binary data, even if it is formally textual…

Comment: Using an old version of Tcl without `ni`? Upgrade! Or use `[lsearch -exact $linesToExclude $line] == -1`.

Answer (score 0):

The name "temp" suggests you don't have a real need for that file. Then you can do the whole thing in Tcl like this:

```
set fIn [open "bigfile"]
set fOut [open "newbigfile" "w"]
while {[gets $fIn line] >= 0} {
    # Skip the unwanted lines
    if {[regexp pat1 $line] && \
      ![regexp pat2 $line] && \
      ![regexp pat3 $line] && \
      ![regexp pat4 $line]} continue
    # Print lines that made it through
    puts $fOut $line
}
close $fOut
close $fIn
```

I don't know what that does for the time it takes to perform the conversion, or if that is even a concern.